# Recover iPad serial number from iCloud backup

Tags: ios, icloud

I won't bore you all with the reasons why but I have an old iPad Pro that I replaced with a new iPad Air last month. I removed the iPad pro from Find my and other icloud services.

I now need the serial number of the device and don't have the box, receipt or anything like that. I thought I had written it down somewhere but stupid me cannot find that 'somewhere'. I don't have any iTunes backups of the device or anything like that, sadly.

What I do have is the old iCloud backup of the device taken just before setting the new device up. Is there any way to download/extract/view the backup of this device in iCloud and see if it has a serial number in there?

Comment: Do you still have the device in your possession? The serial number is in Settings > General > About

Comment: @tetsujin - no. That would have been the first place I would have looked if I had the device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no way to see this without using third-parts softwares. You can try Reincubate [iPhone Backup Extractor](https://reincubate.com/iphone-backup-extractor/). It allows you to import backups from iCloud and see the serial number and other informations.

Here is a preview with an iPhone: [image: iPhone Backup Extractor]

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate the response but that particular piece of software feels quite expensive when there's no guarantee iot will do what I want - all the icloud functionality is blocked off in the demo version.